# Problems with Opencv 2.3.1

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

i have a problem:

I'm using VS Express 2010 and trying to add opencv library to my project, so i already added bin-files to my path, then added lib to properties of my project and 2 Include Directories

this is text of my program:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img=0;
    img = cvLoadImage (argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
}
```

and i have an error: Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLoadImage referenced in function _main c:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\example2\example2\ex2.obj

what did i do wrong?
thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're properly linking to the OpenCV libraries. Since cvLoadImage is part of the HighGUI library within OpenCV, make sure you link to opencv_highui231.lib (in release) and opencv_highguid231.lib (in debug).

To do this in Visual Studio 2010, right-click on your project, then go to Linker->Input and type the name of the library you wish to link to inside Additional Dependencies. Also make sure that the path is accessible, either by typing the relative path into the Additional Dependencies field or by setting Additional Library Directories inside Linker->General.

Comment: i guess i did it write,
here is my lib files at  Linker->Input
opencv_video231d.lib
opencv_ml231d.lib
opencv_legacy231d.lib
opencv_imgproc231d.lib

and my path D:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib;%AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Comment: Another problem may be that those functions are deprecated in 2.3.1. Try including only `opencv.hpp`, and then use `cv::imread()` instead of `cvLoadImage()`.

Comment: i guess it's not the key,  IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "cv::Mat" to "IplImage *" exists c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\example2\example2\ex2.cpp 6

Comment: Yes, you'll also have to say cv::Mat image = cv::imread(...). The syntax will change a bit. But that's probably not the issue: this is definitely a linker issue. Unresolved external means that you have a header telling the compiler that a function exists, but the linker is unable to find its implementation. Double- and triple-check your linker settings to make sure they're being used. Try changing the names of the libs to the wrong values to see if the linker gives you an error (which it should if it can't find them). Make sure the .lib files are from the same version as the headers you use.

Comment: if i change Link Input files it shows me an error like that Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv.lib' C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\example2\example2\LINK

Comment: it works, thanks a lot, a forgot to add opencv_highguid231.lib